# Using data from table as column heading

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with two tables, component_psar and tbl_info. The component_psar table has the field 'tbl_id' which references the corresponding 'id' field in tbl_info.

I need to write a query in which data is taken from tbl_info and used as the heading for that column in component_psar.

So if the component_psar table contained the data:

```
tbl_id | col_1
1      |  Hello
1      |  Hi
1      |  What's up?
```

And then the tbl_info table:

```
id | heading
1  | Greetings
```

I would like it to display as:

```
Greetings
Hello
Hi
What's up?
```

I've written the following SQL query to try and accomplish this:

`SELECT component_psar.col_1 as (SELECT tbl_info.heading FROM tbl_info, component_psar WHERE tbl_info.id = '1') FROM tbl_info, component_psar WHERE (component_psar.tbl_id = '1')`

But this just throws a syntax error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT tbl_info.heading FROM tbl_info, component_psar WHERE tbl_info.id = compo' at line 1`

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how I might accomplish this? Looking at other questions has led me to reading into pivot tables but I haven't seen any way in which this might work for my purposes. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding it.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The operation you are seeking to perform is indeed a "pivot", but it is not natively supported by MySQL (unlike some other RDBMS).  There are ways to accomplish the same result, but first you should consider if this is really what you want/need to do?  What happens when retrieving a resultset with multiple `tbl_info.id`?  You clearly want multiple columns in the results, but how do the rows look?

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that 'id' is the primary key of tbl_info so retrieving multiple results isn't an issue.

Comment: Multiple results might still be returned: consider the case of additional records `(tbl_id, col_1) = (2, 'foo')` in `component_psar` and `(id, heading) = (2, 'bar')` in `tbl_info`.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean here. In that case 'bar' would be the heading for the column in the result set and 'foo' would be the data in the column. I don't see any problem with that...

Comment: My question was: "*You clearly want multiple columns in the results, but how do the rows look?*"  In particular, is `bar` in every row?  On the same row as `Hello`, `Hi` or `What's up`?  Or in a new row?  What's in the other fields?

Comment: Aha, I understand what you mean. I would only want the results for one tbl_id returned - so I would want the data from component_psar and the heading from tbl_info for tbl_id = '1' (for example) but not '2', '3', '4', etc. Looking at it now I realise my SQL query doesn't address this.

Comment: Not only does your existing query not address this, but this lack of meaningful structure suggests that the output format is inappropriate for your data.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Perhaps you're falling into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Comment: I expressed what I'm trying to accomplish in my question. I would like to take the data from tbl_info and use it as the column heading for the result set of the corresponding data in component_psar.

I think the issue of multiple result sets is fairly trivial to this question. Imagine that I'm always going to be getting data for tbl_id = '1' (I'll edit the query in the original question to reflect this) - I would like to know how I might go about using the data from tbl_info as a column heading for component_psar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to separate out the process of retrieving data from the database and formatting it for display.

A simple inner join should work for your query

```
select tbl_info.heading as Heading,component_psar.col_1 as Value 
from tbl_info 
inner join component_psar on component_psar.tbl_id = tbl_info.id
order by tbl_info.heading
```

this will give you the following query results

```
Heading   | Value 
----------+--------------
Greetings |  Hello
Greetings |  Hi
Greetings |  What's up?
```

How you process this for display depends your programming environment.

if your are just printing to the screen the following pseudo code will show how to print the heading only when it changes

```
current_heading = ""
for each row in results
    if row.heading not equal to current_heading   
        current_heading  = row.heading
        print blank line 
        print current_heading 
    end if
    print row.value
loop
```

Comment: This looks like a sensible solution. I would like to have the query return the value from tbl_info as the heading for the data from component_psar if I can, but if that isn't possible I should be able to get the job done with this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

IN MS SQL, it can be achieved as follows:

```
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @col_name varchar(100)
select @col_name = heading from tbl_info where heading = 'greetings'
set @sql = 'select col_1 as ' + quotename(@col_name) + ' from component_psar'
exec(@sql)
```

However, this solution is a code snippet and not one single query.

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:mysql].  And why bother `select heading where heading =`?